# How to Map/Collect Enum.values() to HashMap<Enum,SortedMap<Date,String>>

Tags: java, java-8, enums

I am trying to make use of the stream API in place of loops, and have the follow problem.

I have a method which takes an Enum and returns a SortedMap. I store each map in a list, however I now wish to now store each SortedMap in a map with the Enum name being the key and the SortedMap returned  from`listCritieraResults()`
as the value, how can I do this with the streams API?

Current working List Method

```
List<SortedMap<Date, String>> collectedMaps = Arrays.stream(Criteria.values())
                                    .map(searcher::listCritieraResults)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My incorrect attempt to use Collectors.toMap..

```
Map<String,SortedMap<Date,String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map = Arrays.stream(Criteria.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.name(),c -> searcher.listCritieraResults(c)));
```

Working loop

```
Map<Critiera, SortedMap<Date, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for ( Criteria criteria : Criteria.values()){
            map.put(criteria.name(),searcher.listCritieraResults(criteria));
        }
```

Comment: Does `map` need to be a `HashMap<Criteria,SortedMap<Date,String>>` or could it just be a `Map<Criteria,SortedMap<Date,String>>`?

Comment: yep should just be a map , I've also just seen it should be Map<String,SortedMap<Date,String>>, as I am storing the Enum - name() value on the enum itself

Comment: your code does not  match the error you are getting.

Comment: Yep I was mid edit , then I realised this was my entire problem to begin with ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Map<Criteria,SortedMap<Date,String>>` and use Criteria as key in `toMap` if you want to Criteria as Map's key.

```
Map<Criteria,SortedMap<Date,String>> map = Arrays.stream(Criteria.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c, c -> searcher.listCritieraResults(c)));
```

Or use string as Map key if you use `c.name()` in `toMap`

```
Map<String ,SortedMap<Date,String>> map = Arrays.stream(Criteria.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.name(), c -> searcher.listCritieraResults(c)));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 HashMap<Criteria,SortedMap<Date,String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map = Arrays.stream(Criteria.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.name(),c -> searcher.listCritieraResults(c)));
```

In this, you are calling c.name() which will return a string and not Enum Criteria

Comment: @Eklavya yes you are right. I just copy-pasted the code snippet and wrote what's wrong.